# How to verify in a foreach loop whether the element is last in the collection?

Tags: c#, if-statement, foreach

I have a foreach loop in which I need to verify whether the element is last in the collection I'm iterating on. What I've tried:

```
foreach (var character in list) // list is of type `string` 
{
    if (character == list.Last())
    {

    }
}
```

But in this case if I have `"la la la"` the `if` statement will execute on a second character.

**Question:** How to write the `if` statement so that it will execute when accessing the last element of a sequence?

Comment: So is "la la la" a string?? What is `list`?

Comment: Then use the traditional for as answered

Comment: Why are you doing this? Do you want to do something to all elements except the last, or do you want to update only the last element?

Comment: Do you really need to iterate or do you just want to check the last element?

Comment: I really need to iterate, I'm working (playing) with generics and I need a method that will convert a string, e.g. "true,true,false,true" or "1,2,3,4" into a collection of the generic type.

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi Perhaps this is a bit [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I presume you split the string based on a character like comma and then pass each sub string into something that can determine the type? The need to recognise the last item is due to the need to close off the final type?

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth, yes, I add characters to a StringBuilder instance unless I get to comma or the last element in a list. Then I do conversion, clear the builder variable and continue (break in case of last element).

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi Can you not do something like `"1,2,3,4".Split(',').Select(eachString => ToInt(eachString)).ToList()`? This will avoid a lot of other legwork.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth, thank You, one line of code instead of my 20 lines :)

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi Such is the majesty of Fluent Style and LINQ.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would advise iterating using the index rather than the object reference i.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= list.Count-1; i++)
{
    if (i == list.Count-1)
    {
        // so something special with last item
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just process everything except the last inside the loop and process last outside the loop?

Comment: @RogerRowland there is that aswell, however, doing it as part of the general iteration means you get it all in one go. Also the OP specifically asked how to do it *inside* the loop.

Comment: why iterating at all, it can easily be done without it, see my answer

Comment: @MareInfinitus yeah that's all well and good when you don't need to process the other items in the list...OP says "*I need to verify the element is last in the collection **I'm iterating on***".

Comment: @MareInfinitus in addition to what @James has said, what if you don't know the last character in the list beforehand? I suspect `.Last()` will enumerate internally much in the same way as this solution anyway..

Comment: @DGibbs Why should it iterate? You suspect it and I am quite sure that it will not

Comment: @MareInfinitus the implementation detail of `IEnumerable` is undocumented as I it can differ based on the concrete type implementing it. However, I wouldn't imagine for a string it wouldn't iterate as it's a pretty simple operation `return List[List.Count-1]`. However, there are other scenarios where it potentially could iterate (lazily-loaded collections etc.)

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (var character in list) // list is of type `string` 
{
    if (character == list[list.Count - 1])
    {

    }
}
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/JiopW9).

As an alternative, since `List` implements `IEnumerable` interface, you can use [`Enumerable.Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx) method

> Returns the last element of a sequence.

```
foreach (var character in list) // list is of type `string` 
{
    if (character == list.Last())
    {

    }
}
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/63y0qq).

Comment: I need to verify whether the current character is the last character in a sequence, but this "if" verifies whether the current character equals to the last character

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi I don't understand your comment. Do you mean you check current `char `is the last `char` of the `List`?

Answer (score 0):

Since your list is actually a string, you need to convert it into a list.

```
var elementList = list.Split(" ");
```

You can then find the last element.

```
var lastElement = elementList.LastOrDefault();
```

Just check using IsNullOrEmpty to handle the case of an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself doing this kind of thing often, you can use an extension method which will let you ask if an element in a sequence is the last item.

This was originally written by Jon Skeet; [he called it "Smart Enumerable"](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/smartenumerable.html), and I believe it is part of the [MoreLinq Linq Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)  (also by Jon Skeet).

If you do use such a thing, your code would looks something like this:

```
foreach (var character in list.AsSmartEnumerable()) 
    if (character.IsLast)
        // Do something with character.Value
```

---

Here's a slightly modified copy of Jon Skeet's implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Static class to make creation easier. If possible though, use the extension
/// method in SmartEnumerableExt.
/// </summary>

public static class SmartEnumerable
{
    /// <summary> method to make life easier.</summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of enumerable</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">Source enumerable</param>
    /// <returns>A new SmartEnumerable of the appropriate type</returns>

    public static SmartEnumerable<T> Create<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new SmartEnumerable<T>(source);
    }
}

/// <summary>Wrapper methods for SmartEnumerable[T].</summary>

public static class SmartEnumerableExt
{
    /// <summary>Extension method to make life easier.</summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of enumerable</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">Source enumerable</param>
    /// <returns>A new SmartEnumerable of the appropriate type</returns>

    public static SmartEnumerable<T> AsSmartEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new SmartEnumerable<T>(source);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Type chaining an IEnumerable&lt;T&gt; to allow the iterating code
/// to detect the first and last entries simply.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type to iterate over</typeparam>

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1710:IdentifiersShouldHaveCorrectSuffix", Justification="This is too general to end in 'Collection'")]

public class SmartEnumerable<T>: IEnumerable<SmartEnumerable<T>.Entry>
{
    /// <summary>Enumerable to which we proxy</summary>

    readonly IEnumerable<T> _enumerable;

    /// <summary>Constructor.</summary>
    /// <param name="enumerable">Collection to enumerate. Must not be null.</param>

    public SmartEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        if (enumerable==null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerable");
        }

        this._enumerable = enumerable;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumeration of Entry objects, each of which knows
    /// whether it is the first/last of the enumeration, as well as the
    /// current value.
    /// </summary>

    public IEnumerator<Entry> GetEnumerator()
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = _enumerable.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield break;
            }

            bool isFirst = true;
            bool isLast  = false;
            int  index   = 0;

            while (!isLast)
            {
                T current = enumerator.Current;
                isLast = !enumerator.MoveNext();
                yield return new Entry(isFirst, isLast, current, index++);
                isFirst = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Non-generic form of GetEnumerator.</summary>

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents each entry returned within a collection,
    /// containing the value and whether it is the first and/or
    /// the last entry in the collection's. enumeration
    /// </summary>

    public class Entry
    {
        internal Entry(bool isFirst, bool isLast, T value, int index)
        {
            this._isFirst = isFirst;
            this._isLast  = isLast;
            this._value   = value;
            this._index   = index;
        }

        /// <summary>The value of the entry.</summary>

        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                return _value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Whether or not this entry is first in the collection's enumeration.</summary>

        public bool IsFirst
        {
            get
            {
                return _isFirst;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Whether or not this entry is last in the collection's enumeration.</summary>

        public bool IsLast
        {
            get
            {
                return _isLast;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>The 0-based index of this entry (i.e. how many entries have been returned before this one)</summary>

        public int Index
        {
            get
            {
                return _index;
            }
        }

        readonly bool _isFirst;
        readonly bool _isLast;
        readonly T    _value;
        readonly int  _index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would appear a *little* overkill to me. If I was doing this sort of stuff everywhere I would probably just create a simple `ForEach` extension method which would simply iterate the list and raise a callback method for the last item. Would be interesting to see if that approach vs the `AsSmartEnumerable` would be quicker.

Comment: @James Yes, if that's *all* that SmartEnumerable gave you, I'd agree - but it also gives you the current item's index, and whether its the first item on the list. We do actually use it in various places and it makes the code more readable (particularly when we're using the item's index and would otherwise have to declare an index counter just before the `foreach` loop and increment it in the loop)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to do an action on the last character, then [Mare Infinitus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/863502/mare-infinitus)' code should do the trick.

> What about:

```
var elementList = list.Split(" ");
if (elementList.Last().Equals(character))
{
   // do something here
}
```

> this should do it, no need for foreach.

However, if you want to loop and do a *specific* action for the last character, then you can use a standard `for` loop. [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82586/james)' answer:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= list.Count-1; i++)
{
    if (i == list.Count-1)
    {
        // so something special with last item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have an `IEnumerable`, you have to manually trigger the enumerator. Here is a sample extension method which maybe helps you:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void Action<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> sequenceElement, Action<T> lastElement)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        if (sequenceElement == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sequenceElement");

        if (lastElement == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lastElement");

        T element = default(T);

        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                element = enumerator.Current;

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                sequenceElement(element);
                element = enumerator.Current;
            }

            lastElement(element);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then call it this way:

```
var myElements = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

myElements.Action(value => Console.WriteLine("Something out of the sequence: " + value),
                    value => Console.WriteLine("The last element: " + value));
```